# Spring and Hibernate form binding

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

Ok I am having an issue and have been stuck for a few hours. I am running the current version of spring with Hibernate and need to take data from a form and save it do the database, that's all but it is giving me tons of trouble and have no idea how to go about it. Below is the controller, JSP, Model, and Dao.

Controller

```
private final String addNewView = "addAward";

@RequestMapping(value = "/addAwardType", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String addAwardType() {                                
 LOG.debug("Display form to add a new contact.");        
 return addNewView;                                         
}                      

@RequestMapping(value = "/addAwardType", method = RequestMethod.POST)          
public ModelAndView addAwardType(                                       
  @ModelAttribute("AwardTypeModel") AwardType awardType,                
  BindingResult result) {                                           
 return new ModelAndView(addNewView, "AwardType", new AwardTypeModel(awardType));    
} 



}
```

JSP

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Add AwardType</h2>
<form:form method="POST" commandName="addAwardType">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="AwardType.name">Award Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="AwardType.name" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="AwardType.description">Last Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="AwardType.description" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <form:checkbox path="AwardType.isActive" value="Active"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="AwardType.created"></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="AwardType.created" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Award"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Model

```
public class AwardTypeModel extends BaseModel {

private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private boolean active;
private Date created;
private Date modified;

/**
 * Construct from persistence object
 * A similar constructor will be needed in each model
 * @param dbo - the Persistence Object (data base object)
 */
public AwardTypeModel(AwardType dbo){
    this.id = dbo.getAwardTypeId();
    this.name = dbo.getAwardName();
    this.description = dbo.getDescription();    
    this.active = dbo.isActive();
    this.created = dbo.getCreated();
    this.modified = dbo.getModified();

}



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.eaglecrk.recognition.model.BaseModel#convertToDb()
 */
@Override
public BasePersistence convertToDb() {
    AwardType dbo = new AwardType();
    dbo.setAwardTypeId(this.id);
    dbo.setAwardName(this.name);
    dbo.setDescription(this.description);
    dbo.setActive(this.active);
    dbo.setCreated(this.created);
    dbo.setModified(this.modified);     
    return dbo;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public boolean isActive() {
    return active;
}
public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}
public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
public Date getModified() {
    return modified;
}
public void setModified(Date modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
}
}
```

Comment: Include some logs for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: The problem is I am not sure if I am even doing this right.  I keep getting an java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'addAwardType' available as request attribute error